# Compact version for defining a macro if undefined

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm currently writing a set of modules with parameters that can be defined at compile time. For each value, I'm also specifying a default value, so that a user only needs to define those values they want to change. There is a user-defined include file, which contains the #define macros with the overwritten values.

In my module, I'm using

```
#include "user-defines.h"
#include "module.h"
```

where module.h contains the default definitions.

Currently, I'm using the following pattern for defining the default values in module.h

```
#ifndef somemacro
#define somemacro "default value"
#endif
```

which works, but means a lot of extra typing. It is also three lines instead of one, blowing up the source code.

My question is, is there a more elegant way (e.g. 1 line, not repeating the macro name) to define the default value only in case it is undefined?

Comment: I experimented with a macro `DEFAULT(x,y)` that writes macro code but could not get it to work.

Comment: It doesn't get more compact than three lines.  No, you can't use a macro to write a new macro.

Comment: You can write a script to create the header file from a simpler file. Or you can do it with Find/Replace in your editor. But there's nothing built into C for it.

Comment: Secondly redefining the macro is an indication of the wrong project structure